# Are $n$ random vectors close to an orthonormal basis?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, reference-request

Hel${}$lo, will $n$ vectors $(v_i)_i$ iid uniform on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ probably have $|v_i^\dagger v_j|<\varepsilon \forall i\neq j$ for $n $ large? Than${}$ks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The Marchenko-Pastur distribution with $\lambda,\sigma^2=1$ describes how skewed such a basis will be.